# Disassembly Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Does it exist some way to find a specific address in visual studio ?
when I disassembly my c++ code, when a function is called (ex. call 6A25DDA4 ) I'd like to go to that address, but I cannot understand how to reach it except by moving the bar up or down.
I would like to type the address directly and find it.

Comment: You can indeed type the address right into the disassembly window (at the top) and press Enter. Just make sure to prefix any hex addresses with `0x` for it to be correctly interpreted.

Comment: @Cameron I'm sorry but I cannot find this disassembly window. Where is it ? I'm using visual studio 2017.

Comment: can no one help me ?

Comment: Debug > Windows > Disassembly menu command. Make sure you are doing this while debugging, looking at an assembly listing doesn't help you.

Comment: I am already in the disassembly window. 
Near each instruction there is an address. I want to reach a specific address.
Where can I paste it ?

Comment: is not there some search bar ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a box near the top of the window labelled 'Address:'.  Just type your address in there (prefixed with 0x if it's hex) and press return.

Screenshot:

[image: Visyal Studio Disassembly Window Screnshot]

Comment: thank you my friend for the picture. It works very well for c++. I have tried with c#.
I create a function and then the main call that function. In disassembly window I read Call 00A30438. How ever if I try to write 0x00A30438 an error occurs, it tells me that no address can be found, why ?

Comment: Try that with a Debug build.  In my experience, options with a Release build are limited with C#

Comment: mannagg a baciamell, mo bast nu poc e t facc sape.
OKOK thank you friend you helped me.