# Would like to view Intel opcodes from assembly code

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm, masm64

Would there be any other method on how to go about doing this without having to use the Intel manuals? Would it be possible to simply compile small and short ASM program using MASM64 and then using a hex editor to view the machine code thereafter ?

Comment: While using a hex editor would work, there's a lot of junk inside an exe.  As an alternative, perhaps [this](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm)?

Comment: Usually the easiest thing is to use a disassembler on the resulting .obj or .exe, such as objconv (https://agner.org/optimize/).  MASM might also have a command-line option to make a "listing" output file which has machine code next to your source lines.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548763/compiling-assembly-in-visual-studio

Comment: @PeterCordes I've downloaded the utility and hopefully it work for me. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd thank you for the link it should work for myself in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Disassembly window in Visual Studio while debugging. See [Disassembly Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635231/disassembly-visual-studio)